# Using Okta IdP with an SP that uses dynamic ACSURL

Tags: php, saml, okta

We're in a situation where we are setting up an application to use Okta for SSO. The application is SAML 2.0 compliant, but it does send out an AssertionConsumerServiceURL that is dynamic (a parameter in the URL can take 1 of 2 possible values). The application expects that parameter back to send the user to the proper page after authentication succeeds.

Right now, the authentication succeeds, but the user is not sent to the correct page. We suspect that Okta is not redirecting the user back to the ACSURL that was sent in the original SAML request. We have solved this problem with other IdPs such as simpleSamlPHP by specifying an array of two entries for the ACSl in the metadata configuration. The format would be as follows:

```
$metadata['php-saml'] = array(
  'AssertionConsumerService' => array(
  'https://{server}/index.phpmodule=Users&action=Authenticate&dataOnly=1&platform=base',
  'https://{server}/index.phpmodule=Users&action=Authenticate&dataOnly=1&platform=mobile',
  ),
  'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
  'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'mail',
  'simplesaml.attributes' => false,
  'entityid' => 'php-saml',
);
```

However, the Okta frontend doesn't seem to have an interface to configure this. Is there some way that Okta can be configured at all to accept an incoming dynamic ACSUrl, and to direct the user back to it after the authentication succeeds?

Comment: Two things - does Okta support dynamic or multiple ACS URLs? Something to ask. The second is are you signing the request? In theory, any request you pass with any ACS should be honored, as long as you pass the proper entity ID and sign it with the proper (matching) cert...

Answer (score 0):

In the `AuthnRequest` you can set the `AssertionConsumerServiceURL` attribute and IDP should redirect back to that ACS url. Not sure how you can do that with simpleSAML configuration, but with [lightsaml](http://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-make-AuthnRequest/) lib you can build AuthnRequest yourself as you like.